# How to find cluster index in opencv

Tags: opencv

I want to use bag of description with using OpenCV, so, at the end, I want to find the cluster index of each descriptor for SampleImage, but I do not know how can I find  that, the BOWImgDescriptorExtractor.compute() only returns an array with size of dictronery, but I expect it was an array with size of SIFT extracted descriptros

```
sift = cv2.SIFT(100, contrastThreshold=0.005, edgeThreshold=4, sigma=1.4)

dictionarySize = 20

BOW = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(dictionarySize)

imagepath = 'sampleimage/bow/1.jpg';
imagepath2 = 'sampleimage/bow/2.jpg';
imagepath3 = 'sampleimage/bow/3.jpg';
imagepath4 = 'sampleimage/bow/4.jpg';
imagepath5 = 'sampleimage/bow/5.jpg';

# compute the images
image = cv2.imread(imagepath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
kp, dsc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
BOW.add(dsc)


image = cv2.imread(imagepath2)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
kp, dsc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
BOW.add(dsc)



image = cv2.imread(imagepath3)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
kp, dsc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
BOW.add(dsc)


image = cv2.imread(imagepath4)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
kp, dsc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
BOW.add(dsc)


image = cv2.imread(imagepath5)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
kp, dsc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
BOW.add(dsc)


#dictionary created
dictionary = BOW.cluster()



FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)   # or pass empty dictionary
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
sift2 = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SIFT")
bowDiction = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(sift2, cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2))
bowDiction.setVocabulary(dictionary)
print "bow dictionary", np.shape(dictionary)

#returns descriptor of image at pth
def feature_extract(pth):
    im = cv2.imread(pth, 1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    return bowDiction.compute(gray, sift.detect(gray))




desc1 = feature_extract(imagepath)
for k in desc1:
    print k;

print "Done"
```

the result is

```
[ 0.          0.05        0.02        0.          0.09        0.          0.02
  0.          0.09999999  0.22999999  0.19999999  0.          0.02        0.01
  0.08        0.02        0.06        0.09999999  0.          0.        ]
```

size of the result is 20 (dictionary length), but I expect it to be 100 ( SIFT size)

Comment: It's _correcty_ the size of the dictionary. BoW is computing the sift on your image, comparing each sift to its dictionary, and returning the (normalized) histogram of matches with the dictionary

Comment: so how can I compare two image histogram ?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html